# Spring data Neo4J criteria query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to convert following query with criteria is it possible in Neo4J?

Example:

```
@Query("MATCH (movie:Movie)-[r:RATING]->(), (movie)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor:Actor) " +
           "WHERE movie.id={0} " +
           "RETURN movie.id as movieId, COLLECT(actor.name) AS 'cast', AVG(r.stars) AS 'averageRating'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you want back calculated values and collections of properties. A custom query such as the one you have is the way to go.

**Update:** To query for entities based on simple criteria, you can use [derived finders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_queries_derived_from_finder_method_names) such as `findById(id)`

Comment: Okay but for normal queries is there any other option like in hibernate we have HQL?

Comment: Edited, please accept the answer if it has answered your question, thanks

Comment: Yes for complex queries the answer fulfilled my needs but I'm looking for how can I use **org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate** for other queries.

Comment: Neo4jTemplate will give you a load method (by id), and a loadByProperty which accepts simple property names and values e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/movies/MoviesIntegrationTest.java#L217

Comment: Okay that helped.  Thank you for such quick reply.